# AngularJS ng-options with complex objects (no unique identifier)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I'm trying to use angular's select/ng-options to work with complex objects that does not have an ID. In particular, the data might look like this (an array of accounts):

```
        this.items = [
            {
                prefix: 123,
                number: 111111111,
                bankCode: "0100"
            },
            {
                prefix: 456,
                number: 22222222,
                bankCode: "0200"
            },
            {
                prefix: 789,
                number: 33333333,
                bankCode: "0300"
            }
        ];
```

I want to have a select-box with items from this array, formatted using custom angular filter (format "prefix-number/bankCode"). When an item is selected, it should be stored in controller.selected as complex account item, eg.

```
            this.selected = {
                prefix: 123,
                number: 111111111,
                bankCode: "0100"
            };
```

Now, this works OK using the snipped bellow.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
        .filter('accountNumberFilter', function () {
            return function (input) {
                return input.prefix + "–" + input.number + "/" + input.bankCode;
            };
        })
        .controller('MyCtrl', function () {
            this.selected = null;
            this.items = [
                {
                    prefix: 123,
                    number: 111111111,
                    bankCode: "0100"
                },
                {
                    prefix: 456,
                    number: 22222222,
                    bankCode: "0200"
                },
                {
                    prefix: 789,
                    number: 33333333,
                    bankCode: "0300"
                }
            ];

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <select
            ng-model="ctrl.selected"
            ng-options="acct | accountNumberFilter for acct in ctrl.items">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <pre>Selected: 
{{ ctrl.selected | json : spacing }}</pre>
</div>
```

The problem is **when I navigate from one page to another**, storing the selected item to a service. After returning to the page with selectbox (eg. having an item in ctrl.selected), **no item in selectbox is selected**. I understand that this is due to object inequality, so I'm looking for a way to tell angular "two account items are considered equal iif prefix==prefix && number==number && bankCode==bankCode".

This snipped demonstrates this situation (the only difference to the above is that controller have

```
            this.selected = {
                prefix: 123,
                number: 111111111,
                bankCode: "0100"
            };
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
        .filter('accountNumberFilter', function () {
            return function (input) {
                return input.prefix + "–" + input.number + "/" + input.bankCode;
            };
        })
        .controller('MyCtrl', function () {
            this.selected = {
                    prefix: 123,
                    number: 111111111,
                    bankCode: "0100"
                };
            this.items = [
                {
                    prefix: 123,
                    number: 111111111,
                    bankCode: "0100"
                },
                {
                    prefix: 456,
                    number: 22222222,
                    bankCode: "0200"
                },
                {
                    prefix: 789,
                    number: 33333333,
                    bankCode: "0300"
                }
            ];

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <select
            ng-model="ctrl.selected"
            ng-options="acct | accountNumberFilter for acct in ctrl.items">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <pre>Selected: 
{{ ctrl.selected | json : spacing }}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store this.items somewhere else so that it is not destroyed and recreated every time your controller is instantiated. Because then it is a new array of new objects that will not be equal to what you have saved. Perhaps put it into a service also.

Comment: is there another way? I need to recreate them (retrieve from remote url) since contents of the array might change as user moves around the site.

Comment: Yes, in that case you need to do a comparison to find the item that matches what you saved. So, even though there is no unique ID, the properties in each item should be unique, as in, why would you have 2 items with the same prefix, number, bankCode. So then use some library preferably like lodash js to find the item in the array based on what you saved and set that as the selected

Comment: yeah, that is what I want to do but do not know how to implement it. In java I'd make the objects comparable and implement the compareTo function, but that is not the case in JS.

Comment: you just have to do it yourself
var l = items.length;
while(l--){
  
  if(items[l].number === savedItem.number /*&& etc..*/){
    
    return items[l];
  }
}

Comment: yeah, I understand I'll have to write the comparison by hand, but how do I plug it into my/angularjs ng-options code?